# Passing a local variable to a function that I can only make limited changes to

Tags: javascript, callback, global-variables, jsonp, closures

I am just starting to get into JavaScript and couldn't find an exact scenario like this yet on SO, so I'm going to try my luck. I have two functions in an external JS file which create video feeds on our website:

```
function getVideos() {
    //gets a list of videos
}

//callback function automatically called by getVideos()
function response(jsonData) { //can't change this line
    var resp = document.getElementById("resp"); //can change this line and any subsequent lines
    //parses data and populates resp
}
```

Then, from the HTML side, we just call getVideos() and the video feed will be created and populated.

However, I want to be able to pass any element ID I want into response() so that we can create multiple video feeds in different places on the same page. The thing is I can't change the function declaration of response() to include another parameter. Or at least I'm not led to believe I can by the company hosting our videos.

I've tried wrapping response() with getVideos() and passing an element ID from there, but then response() doesn't get called, and the only solution I can think of is resorting to storing an element ID in a global variable, which I know is a no-no in general in JavaScript.

**My question is:** Do I just bite the bullet and use a global variable, or is there another way?

For more info, here is our JS code as it stands now (with the closure): http://www.thebearrocks.com/Other/js/videoFeed/createVideoFeed.js
And here is the tutorial on response() we're following from the host of our videos: http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/making-media-api-calls-dynamic-script-tags

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! There's no need to add tags to your title, there's a tag system for that. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190 for the general discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and tips, Patrick!

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you can change and what you can't. In particular, can you change the `getVideos` function, the composition of the JSON response, and the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

may be you can use arguments? like so:

```
function response(jsonData) { //callback function automatically called by getVideos()
    var elemId = arguments.length<2 ? "resp" : arguments[1]+"";
    var resp = document.getElementById(elemId);
    //parses data and populates resp
}
```

or, declare second argument what has default value like this:

```
function response(jsonData, elemId) { 
    elemId = elemId || "resp";
    var resp = document.getElementById(elemId);
    //parses data and populates resp
}
```

in this case function can be called as with one or two arguments

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I don't think I can change response() to accept more arguments than it already has. The tutorial link I put up from the company hosting our videos specifies only one argument for response(). I will look into your first suggestion though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried wrapping response() with getVideos() and passing an element ID from there, but then response() doesn't get called, and the only solution I can think of is resorting to storing an element ID in a global variable, which I know is a no-no in general in JavaScript.
>
> My question is: Do I just bite the bullet and use a global variable, or is there another way?

No. Not the id variable needs to become global, but your local `response` function needs to for getting called back from the [JSONP script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) - you're going to create a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

You can "export" it by calling

```
window.response = mylocalResponseFunction; // you did name that local var "response"
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by exporting. Can you clarify? I am still a bit new to JS.

Comment: Export it from the local scope where it was declared, so that the function can be called "from outside". There are various possibilities to do so, for example `return`ing it from the scoping function (`createVideoFeed` in your case), adding it as a callback somewhere or - like here - assigning it to a variable in a higher scope. Did you read the linked question on closures?